# Jdbc DB2 connectivity getting hanged

Tags: java, jdbc, db2

I am using jdbc to connect to DB2 instance. I am using the jar - jcc-11.5.0.0.jar.

The code I am using is :

```
Class.forName("com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Driver");
Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:db2://<server>:<port>/<database>"," 
<userid>","<password>")
Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
```

Issue is that the program hangs there, its not producing any exception or output.

Is there anything I need to do so that it gets a connection successfully

While trying to connect using Db2 client we are getting error:

[jcc][t4][2030][14161][4.28.11] A communication error occurred during operations on the connection's underlying socket, socket input stream,
or socket output stream. Error location: Connection timeout check. Message: Connection timed out. ERRORCODE=-4499, SQLSTATE=08001

Comment: Does the same connection-string work with a different java application for example any application like DbVisualiser, SquirrelSQL, DBeaver, IBM Data-Studio?   in other words, is it your application, or is there a problem with either the connection-string or the target Db2-server connectivity

Comment: The `getConnection()` call can be sometimes slow (a few seconds?) but apart from that the rest should be pretty fast.

Comment: Exactly where does it hang? In the `Class.forName` or in `DriverManager.getConnection(..)` or in `con.createStatement()`?

Comment: Its getting hanged at the time of creating the connection, there is nothing printed in the console i.e error or any exception. Its stays in the hanged condition for 20-30 mins before I manually terminated the process

Comment: @Avishek Your edit is unclear, ambiguous, exactly *which tool* of the Db2-client are you trying to use. Have you verified the target Db2-server is connectable, and that the port is open all the way? How have you verified that the target Db2-server is listening on that port?  Do you have any competent experienced troubleshooting people on site. Stuff like this should be solved by competent onsite people in a few minutes.

Comment: I am using DBeaver for connection. When I use DBeaver its getting this socket error. But when I use jdbc connection there is no error or exception at the console only hangs there while getting connection